# Can't read special characters with scanf

Tags: arrays, c, char, scanf

I'm building a system and i need a char inside a struct to receive a name and 2 values, but when I see the result, the name is always broken from a special character.

```
#define NOMINMAX
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct
{
    float preco;
    int quant;
    char* prod[50];
    
} info;

void imprime(info j)
{
    printf("||  Produto: %s  ||  preço: %.2f  ||  quantidade: %d  ||\n", j.prod, j.preco, j.quant);
}

int main()
{
    SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
    SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
    system("color 0F");
            
    info lojas[50];
    
    for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
    {
        printf("Digite o nome do produto: ");
        scanf(" %[^\n]s", &lojas[x].prod);
        printf("\nDigite o preço do produto: ");
        scanf(" %f", &lojas[x].preco);
        printf("\nDigite a quantidade desejada do produto: ");
        scanf(" %d", &lojas[x].quant);
        system("cls");
    }
    
    for (int x = 0; x < 1; x++)
    {
        imprime(lojas[x]);
    }   
}
```

imput:

```
Digite o nome do produto: Açucar

Digite o preço do produto: 1

Digite a quantidade desejada do produto: 1
```

expected output:

```
||  Produto: Açucar  ||  preço: 1.00  ||  quantidade: 1  ||
```

result received

```
||  Produto: A  ||  preço: 1.00  ||  quantidade: 1  ||
```

I think the problem may be in these lines:

```
SetConsoleCP(CP_UTF8);
SetConsoleOutputCP(CP_UTF8);
```

without them the code works, but the special characters inside printf stop working.
I already tried to use the <locale.h> library but for reasons I don't know it doesn't work in my compiler

I use the embarcadeiro dev-c++

Comment: Please note that `%[^\n]s` is a "beginner's hybrid" error. The format spec `%[]` is not a subset of `%s` but a distinct format specifier in its own right, with different characteristics.

Comment: I tried your program on my computer, with a few modifications: (1) I skipped the `#include <windows.h>` and the calls to `SetConsoleCP()`, `SetConsoleOutputCP()`, and `system("color")`. (2) I changed `char* prod[50]` in the `info` structure to `char prod[50]`. (3) I changed `%[^\n]s` to `%[^\n]`, and on that same line, I got rid of the `&`.  With those changes, your program worked properly for me.  (On my system, I get full UTF-8 handling without doing anything special.)

Comment: Conclusion: your code is mostly fine, and your problems with "special" characters are the usual ones in getting Unicode to work well under Windows at all. (Sorry, I can't help you with those, as I don't use Windows much.)

Comment: Definitely try again with my changes (2) and (3), but I'm afraid you'll probably still have issues with the `ç` character.

Comment: Also, you should try to figure out how to enable more warnings with your compiler, or use a better compiler.  My compiler warned me immediately about the problems behind (2) and (3).  Learning C can be frustrating enough under the best of circumstances, but a good compiler can really help you with at least a few of those frustrations.

Comment: @SteveSummit I tried what you said and it worked, but as you predicted I still had problems with the ç. Do you have a better compiler suggestion? I use this one because it's the pattern my college professor uses

Comment: @NikolasRian Sorry, no, as I said, I don't use Windows much.  I'm sure there are others here that would have good suggestions, though.

Comment: @SteveSummit Thank you very much for your help. Now I'm going to hunt for a new compiler to use.

Comment: @NikolasRian Fair warning: A better compiler is an excellent idea, but it's probably not going to help you with handling those special characters.  There are ways to get special characters to work better under Windows, but the details are elaborate, and depend to some extent on which version of Windows you're using.  The site http://utf8everywhere.org/ ha a lot of good information, although it's targeted more towards production programs, not so much little "teaching" programs like yours.

Comment: With MS Visual C and those same mods (but still with the `windows.h` and console function calls) Your word `"preço"` was output to the console, but the entry of `"Açucar"` (copy/pasted) caused a stall, until <Enter> was again pressed and all that was output later was a squiggle. I never have cause to use non-ASCII coding with a C console program, so I can't offer a solution. But I can confirm that the `ç` output to the console from the program text was a 2-byte unicode `C3 A7` visible as a single character.

Comment: `char* prod[50];` --> `char prod[50];` Otherwise, compiling with warnings enabled (`-Wall`) would flag your first `scanf`

Comment: Note that the Code page set by those console functions has nothing to do with unicode, but controls what the code page is used by characters 128 to 255. So it's only relevant for console output.

Comment: MS VC says about [`scanf`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/scanf-scanf-l-wscanf-wscanf-l?view=msvc-170) *`scanf` doesn't currently support input from a UNICODE stream.*

Comment: @SteveSummit Rather than suggest `"%[^\n]"`, which is worse than `gets()`, consider using a lead space and a width limit like `" %49[^\n]"`.

Comment: Nikolas Rian, research `wscanf()` in stead of `scanf()` for "Açucar".  Tip: check return value of  `scanf(" %[^\n]s", &lojas[x].prod);`.  What was it?
.

Answer (score -1):

**Hi,** that's because in C, you should scan a string with another function like gets().

For that IDK if you have to add the library <strings.h> but an example is:

```
int main () {
   char str[50];
   printf("Inster a string: ");
   gets(str);
   printf("The string is: %s",str);
   return(0);
}
```

*I recommend you to add the library <string.h> because its easier to make more functions.*

See you :)

Comment: Sorry, this is not a useful answer.  The `gets` function is obsolete and should not be used.  The similar `fgets` function is fine — but if `scanf` can't read accented characters on a given system, it's highly unlikely that `fgets` will be able to do any better.

Comment: PhilipSanM, `gets()` is no longer part of the C library since 2011 (11 years).  Suggest using more up-to-date references and advice.